# Tags in RSS bodies

Tags: feature-request, tags, feed

It would be really nice to have tags for questions listed in the body (or title) of RSS items. Quite often it's impossible to determine technology, programming language, etc. from body text itself.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it already is -- for example [the feed for this very question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/56389) contains:

```
<category scheme="../feeds/question/56389/tags" term="feature-request"/>
<category scheme="../feeds/question/56389/tags" term="tags"/>
<category scheme="../feeds/question/56389/tags" term="rss"/>
```

Is there something else you're looking for?

Comment: Well, I guess this is more a reader problem than StackExchange but Google Reader is probably the most popular reader in the world and it doesn't show this info (or I'm stupid and don't know where to look). So I think it would help if tags were visible right at the end of the question body (or something like this).

Comment: @Alan: I have a possible solution for you in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have written a small application called [stack2rss](https://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service) which converts API requests to RSS feeds.

It also includes the tags in feeds for questions.

Here is an example:

> http://quickmediasolutions.com/stack2rss/stackoverflow/questions?tagged=c&body=true

It returns all questions tagged `C` and includes the tags for each question in the body of the feed entry. I just tried it in Google Reader and it works.

Comment: how come this doesn't work with MathOverflow.net?

Comment: @Dror: It's not a Stack Exchange 2.0 site.