# Show tags in feeds

Tags: feature-request, tags, feed

I would like the content in the feeds to include the tags used on a question. Sometimes the tags provide useful information which is not reflected in the post body (for example, some SO users only mention the language they are using via tag). Here's a sample markup:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tags in RSS bodies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56389/tags-in-rss-bodies)